# When using the Generate Scripts wizard in SQL Server 2005, where is the Script Behaviour option for DROP followed by CREATE?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Using the Generate Scripts wizard in SQL Server Management Studio 2005 (right click a database -> Tasks -> Generate Scripts...). There is an option for Script Behaviour. The description for the option is as follows:

**Script Behaviour**

> Generate the script as DROP statements, CREATE
>   statements, or DROP statements
>   followed by CREATE statements.

However, there are only two options to select from:

> - Generate CREATE statements only.
> - Generate DROP statements only.

Where is the option to DROP and CREATE? Is there a way to get this behaviour, or have they simply left it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Management Studio (2005 SP3), when i right click on a database -> Tasks -> Generate Scripts, after I select my database and choose Next, the wizard then presents me with a number of script options, with most of them being True/False settings.

To achieve DROP and CREATE I expect you would need to set **both** the properties below to true.

- Script Drop
- Script Create

By default i think **Script Create** is set to TRUE and **Script Drop** is set to FALSE.

Comment: Unfortunately, these options are not available to me. Perhaps I have a different version. I'll try installing SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 3 and see if it has an update for management studio.

Comment: My Version is 9.00.4035.00 which does indicate its Server Pack 3 (Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185)

Comment: Thanks. Service Pack 3 has addressed this issue.